# Oracle- Can't access objects from other users schema

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

I have an oracle database with 2 users. I have created a table in one of the user accounts, but cannot access the table from the other account ("table or view does not exist"). It doesn't work when I prefix the table name with the username either.

I've also created a public synonym for the new table but am still having the issue.

User A cannot access any objects out of B (even with prefixing), but user B can access objects from user A (has to prefix).

What am I missing?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you granted select rights on B's table?

```
connect userb/password    
grant select on table_from_b to usera;

connect usera/password
select * from userb.table_from_b;
```